# Unable to fetch data using React/Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs

Working on a Spring/React app. Fetch isn't getting any data (at least, nothing is being rendered) yet if I go to the Spring server (localhost) the data is definitely there. The data to be returned is a 2d array - could this be a problem with JSON?

Here he is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
   this.state = {
     isLoading: true,
     groups: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/api/test')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ groups: data });
} 

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> {this.state.groups} </p>
    </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Here's my controller

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;


import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;


@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HelloController {

    public Map a = new Map();


    @GetMapping("/test")
    Tile[][] b() {
        return a.getMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you write `<p> {JSON.stringify(this.state.groups)} </p>`? You most likely want to process your array further, like e.g. using `map` and return some JSX for every element in the array.

Comment: Can you tell us if some error is happening in your React application? I recommend that you use chrome dev tools, inspect inside the Network tab, and try to see if you're getting some request error there. Or even in console, are you getting some error?

Comment: @Tholle The empty array '[]' is displayed in the browser.

Comment: @inafalcao - no errors in the console or network tab. React act compiles fine when I run npm start with no warnings/errors

Comment: Take a look not in compile time, but at the fetch time.

Comment: If you add a `.catch(error => console.error(error));` at the bottom of your fetch, do you get errors in the console then? Is the request successful if you check the networks tab when the fetch is run?

Comment: Thanks for responses. I seem to be getting blocked due to CORS. no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. I have Cross Origin annotation on my controller - is there other configuration I have to go through?

Comment: Importing CORS related annotations into Application.java, not just controller, seems to have got it working. Thanks everyone.

Comment: That's weird, `@CrossOrigin` should be only applied to controllers or controller methods. Not sure if it actually has any effect when you apply it to the `Application` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your spring app  doesn’t run on the same port as your React app, while your fetch requests resources from the same server as your react, without proxy or changing your request base url,  you won’t get anything from your spring app.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, in my package.json file I have proxy setup:     "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"